# Dask read_parquet with pyarrow engine

Tags: python, dask

I have a pandas dataframe. I am saving it to parquet using spark and then trying to read via dask. The issue is that the partitioned column is not being read back using pyarrow engine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i64': np.arange(1000, dtype=np.int64),
                            'Ii32': np.arange(1000, dtype=np.int32),
                            'f': np.arange(1000, dtype=np.float64),
                            't': [datetime.datetime.now()] * 1000,
                            'e': ['1'] * 998 + [None,'1'],
                            'g' : [np.NAN] * 998 + [None, ''],
                            'bhello': np.random.choice(['hello', 'Yo', 'people', '1'], size=1000).astype("O")})

spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName("Python Spark arrow compatibility") \
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
            .getOrCreate()
        spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
        #enable metadata write from spark
        spark.conf.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata",  "true")
        #convert pandas df to spark df
        sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

        #write to parquet
        sparkDf.write.parquet(path, partitionBy=['bhello'])

        #use dask to read the above saved parquet with pyarrow engine
        df2 = dd.read_parquet('hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/tmp/test/outputParquet10',
                              engine='pyarrow',
                             )

        print(df2.columns)
        self.assertIn('bhello', df2.columns)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Checking this, pyarrow engine seems to find the partitioning column without trouble, as does fastparquet (in which case the path needs to be a glob-string, not just the directory, if spark is not configured to write a metadata file). This is with local folders, not HDFS.

Comment: @mdurant  I tried the above with the below setting to write metadata 
       spark.conf.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata",  "true") but still the same issue. Also tried with the glob path  
     'hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/tmp/test/outputParquet10/*/*.parquet'  but to no luck

Comment: For pyarrow, maybe related: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3518
Is there a good reason not to try with fastparquet?

Comment: We are currently using fastparquet itself but pyarrow gives me a speedup of 10x while scanning, hence want to migrate to that

Comment: That is quite a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that this is a minimal working example. Hence my solution would be to read it using `dask` and then convert it using `fastparquet` or `pyarrow` engines.

Code is below.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf=dd.read_csv('/destination/of/your/file/file.format_name')
ddf.to_parquet('/destination/of/your/file/file.parquet',engine = 'fastparquet') #default is fastparquet if both engines are installed.
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Michael